# XAMP setup drupal

Tags: drupal, xampp

This is what happens when I browse into my website on XAMP.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vyntsv1/includes/lock.inc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your Drupal installation can not access your database. You should check the following:

- Is your Xampp database service running: this needs to be turned on separately.
- Go to the phpmyadmin page of your Apache installation (usually at localhost/phpmyadmin)
  and try to log in using the username and password you set during your Drupal installation (you can find these in sites/default/settings.php). I assume that you are indeed using a local database, so that part should be correct, if not you should fix it. If you are not able to log in using these credentials, check what the right ones are (you set these during your SQL database installation) and correct them in the settings.php file.